# Facebook like button no longer shows up in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-like

I am developing a [bulk sms](http://www.smsbooth.com) application using JSF. I added the facebook like button but it doesn't show up on chrome (it shows up in IE). I checked the console and found a message - "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT". My [other site](http://www.naija-passion) that formerly used to display the button also no longer shows it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That means that one of the extensions you are using has blocked that request … so disable whatever that extension that might be … adblocker, privacy-addon, whatever.

Comment: I've found the solution. It was a default setting in a new version of Avast blocking social networks.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question because I was searching for "net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" while developing a website using a purchased template.

The issue was that I checked "block social media buttons" in AdBlockPlus settings. I did not use any tracking buttons on my website, though.
**The template used banned names in classes and file names**. For example, there was a CSS class *icon-social-facebook* and an image *icon-social-facebook.png*. It turned out that AdBlockPlus was configured to use this list https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/fanboy-social.txt which blocked website elements with "icon-social-" in their names.